# Can browser windows be assigned to specific Mission Control Spaces?

Tags: spaces, mission-control, web-browser

I usually run MacOS with three Mission Control Spaces and a distinct web browser window (Firefox) in each of them. My settings on Firefox are to open previous windows and tabs when restarting.

However, all windows reappear on of the Spaces, and are not distributed among the three running.

Can browser windows be assigned to specific Mission Control Space?

Set up three separate MacOS desktops
Create distinct Firefox windows in each desktop
Firefox settings are to open previous windows and tabs when restarting
Close down Firefox
Restart Firefox, to have all three windows appear on one desktop